# Remove or clear background-image :url(image/png) after success submit in modal bootsrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, bootstrap-modal

I have been developing form which has resize and crop got tutorial [here](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/://) in modal bootstrap all working fine, but I need to remove old images in modal bootstrap after successful uploads. I use jQuery to remove them, but nothing happened

Here is my JS:

```
success: function(data) {
$('#forminfo').trigger("reset"); //reset form 
$('#myModalinformation').find('form')[0].reset();
}
```

The form still keep old images so after debug and think all command in above is remove all input type, textarea, radio button and checkbox so i debug by inspect elemen so i got this

here is my inspect elemen
[image]

Then here is my modal
[image]

Thanks for some help so i can solved by digging issue in github

```
success: function(data) {
$('#forminfo').trigger("reset"); //reset form 
$('#myModalinformation').find('form')[0].reset();
$('.cropit-image-preview').css('background-image', ''); //remove preview-images
$('.cropit-image-background').removeAttr('src'); //remove background images
}
```